# Is there any built in function in pandas to subtract various columns to manipulate a stacked bar chart?

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, pandas-groupby, stacked

I hope I do not brake too much rules (this is my first post).

First Things first: I'm sorry, but I cannot post an image of my plots or Code right now. So I created a pretty image in paint. On the left side you see what I want to create, on the right side you see what I create right now.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAoyW.png)

I was able to make a barchart as shown on the left side with lots of detours. Since I have to analyse lots of data in similar charts I want to use the built in plot function of Pandas.

What I need: stacked bar chart, where the values are not summed up (like shown in the right image) but the difference of the values are summed up (like shown in the left image). So if `s1 = 2` and `s2 = 6` and i just do some stuff like `groupby().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)` I got stacked bars which end at `y=2` for s1 and `y=8` for s2 (like shown in the right diagram). 
How can I modify my code so that I will get `y=2` for s1 and `y=6` for s2?.

I thought about `diff()`, but the result was definetly not like expected.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks for your adviced and best regards
Arnfried

Comment: Have you tried creating column with calculated difference, say `s3 = s2-s1` and then plotting s1 and s3?

Comment: I'm sorry, i think I failed explaining it. Lets say the y values are y1=1, y2=3, y3=5. All the values are in the same row. When I stack the bars the three bars end at the values 1, 4 and 9. I want them to end at 1, 3 and 5. I know that I can just create a list with the values y1=1, y2= 2 (y2-y1) and y3=3 (y3-y2). But I hope there is a Pandas-inhouse solution.